# How to convert a sequence of numbers into a column

Tags: r, sequence

I'm generating the ecdf of a set of over 80,000 numbers, but the output is a horizontal sequence of multiple rows and I would like it to be a single column.  Here's some code.

```
dat <- c(1,1,1,2,5,4,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,9)
p <- ecdf(dat)
p(seq(0,9,1))
```

Comment: Just do `df1 <- data.frame(col1 = p(seq(0,9,1)))`

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to not display the first column of numbers?

Comment: Did you meant `df1 <- data.frame(col1 = p(seq(0,9,1))[-1])`

Comment: They're still there.

Comment: Not clear what you meant.  Can you please update the post with expected output

Comment: I assume that in creating the data frame, R adds an index in the first column. I would just like to remove that.  If it's not possible, no big deal.  Thanks for this.

Comment: If you meant `row.names`, it is by default. You can have a `matrix` with no dimnames. i.e. `matrix(p(seq(0, 9, 1)))`